# Adding Image to UITableView in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swift2

I have a `UITableView` with a custom prototype cell and is the subclass to the superclass `UITableView`. I'm trying to add multiple photos to the Table with an `NSMutableArray`:

Here is my code:

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PillarTableViewCell



cell.titleLabel.text = self.objects.objectAtIndex(row) as? String

        cell.pillarIcon.image = self.imageObjects.objectAtIndex(row) as? UIImage
```

Each row produced has a `label` and a `imageIcon`. I have never added an image to a `UITableView` and the above code is as close as I have come. The error I receive is

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

This error makes me think it will not put to things in one row based off the code I have written. Is this correct?

How do I solve this issue. 
Thanks.

As per request here is the `numberOfRowsInSection` portion:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return objects.count + staticObjects.count
    }
```

Comment: ok..please check that you are passing same array in both "cellForRowAtIndexPath" & "numberOfRowsInSections". Seems that array does not have value at an index & this occurs when you pass different arrays.

Comment: So, IDK which line you crash on but the error is telling you that either self.objects or self.imageObjects has less than 2 things in it when you try to access it. If you ask an array for an object at an index that does not exist, it will crash.

Comment: Why `row` and not `indexPath.row` ?

Comment: Could you post the code for numberOfRowsInSections also?

Comment: @dpstart sorry for the long delay had some things to take care of. The reason for `row` and not `indexPath.row` is that I have two prototype cells. One that only has one object and the 2nd has multiple objects that can increase or decrease. So I had to do math and create a variable that would hold the `index`.

Comment: @Dare I have 4 objects in the `self.objects` and 3 in the `self.imageObjects`

Comment: @kye I posted the code you requested.

Comment: @Dare I think your response is going to be that I need both `self.object` and `self.imageObjects` to equal each other which makes sense. The App works but it is now not showing the image. I added the images to the file but am I requesting the file into the program wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the number of sections in your `UITableView` is higher than the number of indexes within your objects Array. 
Try adding a condition clause to your `numberOfRowsInSection` function.

```
     var row = Int;
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            var count = 0;
            if (row == 0){ //UITableView index starts at 0
           count = staticObjects.count
           }
            else{
           count = objects.count    
           } 
      return count;
```

}

```
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           let row = indexPath.row;
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PillarTableViewCell
    cell.titleLabel.text = self.objects[indexPath.row] // or use row doesn't matter
   cell.pillarIcon.image = self.imageObjects.objectAtIndex(row) as? UIImage
   return cell;
}
```